# pycassa timeseries data on multiple keys

Tags: python, cassandra, time-series, pycassa

I am trying to make a newsfeed for twitter clone - that shows the newest tweets for a selection of users, rather than newest tweets from all users or newest tweets from a single user.

I have UUID keys stored in individual keys, e.g:

```
user1, {UUID01: '', UUID02: '', UUID03: '', UUID04: ''}
user2, {UUID05: '', UUID06: '', UUID07: '', UUID08: ''}
user3, {UUID09: '', UUID10: '', UUID11: '', UUID12: ''}
user4, {UUID13: '', UUID14: '', UUID15: '', UUID16: ''}
```

End each UUID relates to a tweets in another column family:

```
UUID01, { ... }
UUID02, { ... }
UUID03, { ... }
```

Now, I can efficiently get tweets time ordered for either all users, or for a single user. But how can I get time ordered events for e.g., user1, user2, and user3?

Note that user1 could have lots of new tweets, but user 2 could have few few new tweets.

I have considered making a 'newsfeed' column family that has the UUIDs for the tweets of all the users that a user is following, but this sheer level of data redundancy seems...overkill. Is this a more sensible approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sort (merge) on client, or duplicate into a separate newsfeed, are basically your two options.  Pick your poison.

FWIW, I saw a research paper that I can't find anymore, analyzing which is better.  It concluded that duplicating is better up to a certain threshold of tweet volume. (~10000 per user, IIRC.)